# What should be more efficient - Appending results to a new table or Inner Join with the existing table

Tags: sql

I have a `Original_Table` that contains an empty column called `Results` (which is to be populated using python code being run on other columns in `Original_Table`). The primary key in this `Original_Table` is ROWID

I also have an **empty** (currently) table called `Results_Table`  that has the same columns/data format as `Original_Table`

What I am doing currently:

1. The `Original_Table` contains 1 million records , so I am creating
   batches of 100 samples as a `Temporary_Small_Table` and calculating
   `Results` column.
2. Then I append the `Temporary_Small_Table` to the initially empty
   `Results_Table`

As you can notice , I do not update the `Original_Table` with the data in my `Temporary_Small_Table` as I imagine a join across `Temporary_Small_Table` (100 records) X `Original_Table`(1 million records) will be very inefficient. So I simply keep on appending my `Temporary_Small_Table` to the `Results_Table`.

I wanted recommendations on what's the correct way to do this (**Joining to `Original_Table`** or **Appending to `Results_Table`** ).

One obvious consequence of  **Appending to `Results_Table`** is wasting storage space for a brand new table.

Just few additional background points:

1. I am creating batches for running my python code in multiple threads.
2. I am doing this on the Azure Databricks platform. [This](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2017/11/21/rdms-databricks-cloud-based.html#:%7E:text=In%20order%20to%20store%20this,service%20by%20Azure%20and%20AWS.) link tells me the database is MySQL and PostgreSQL operated as a service by Azure and AWS.
3. The join I am speaking about will be done on ROWID(it's the primary
   key as mentioned in the beginning)
4. For point #1 , I am already splitting my batches with predetermined
   row ids in the table , hence different threads picking up the same
   row from the  `Original_Table` is not an issue at the moment for me.
   How to avoid the same row from the  `Original_Table` from getting
   picked up without predetermining row ids  for each batch is a
   different topic which I would park for later

Comment: Which database are you using? What keys - especially Primary Keys - do these tables have?

Comment: Is the calculation really so complex that it cannot be done in SQL, thus allowing you to run a single UPDATE statement on the whole table?

Comment: @simon at rcl
The primary key is RowID which I had to create manually as no other column was suitable. I have now edited my question with this info.... As to the database question , Apologies if I don't know the correct answer but I am using [Azure Databricks DBFS](https://docs.databricks.com/dbfs/index.html)

Comment: @Jonathan Willcock It's the use of Python libraries like Spacy for NLP purposes , so can't be done using SQL. For example, gauging the "Readability" of an english sentence and finding Organization names using NER (Named Entity Recognition)

Comment: @ simon at rcl    [This](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2017/11/21/rdms-databricks-cloud-based.html#:~:text=In%20order%20to%20store%20this,service%20by%20Azure%20and%20AWS.) link tells me the database is  MySQL and PostgreSQL operated as a service by Azure and AWS.